# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymc3'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, pymc3

I'm trying to import PyMC3 library in Jupyter Notebook's Python 3 kernel. I've already installed pymc3 initials in Anaconda Prompt (Miniconda3) using:

```
conda install theano
conda install pygpu
pip install pymc3
```

And when I try to import it in Jupyter Notebook:

```
import pymc3 as pm
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-1f817cf6472a> in <module>
      1 # PyMC3 for Bayesian Inference
----> 2 import pymc3 as pm

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymc3'
```

Any solutions to this problem guys...

Comment: check your installed environment with currently active environment

Answer (score -1):

You have installed the pymc3 to other python environment that you are using to import it.

#### Check your python executable location

Inside your script, use

```py
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

To get the path to the python executable you are using. Lets say it is `C:\python\python.exe`.

#### Install the package

Then, install the package using

```
<path_to_python.exe> -m pip install pymc3
```

This is the bulletproof way installing packages with pip, when you have multiple python installations or virtual environments on your system.

Comment: does this mean i have to reinstall pymc3 at the path of my Jupyter Notebook file ?

Comment: I updated the answer. You need to use the same python executable to install the package that you're using to run the script. Note that `pip install` translates to `python -m pip install` but sometimes it might not be clear which python executable it uses. That's why `<path-to-python> -m pip install` is clearer .